# Why am I able to write a module parameter with READ ONLY permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, kernel, sysfs

I wrote the following simple linux kernel module to test the param feature:

```
#include<linux/module.h>

int a = 5;
module_param(a, int, S_IRUGO);

int f1(void){

        printk(KERN_ALERT "hello world\n");
        printk(KERN_ALERT "  value passed: %d \n", a);
        return 0;
}

void f2(void){

        printk(KERN_ALERT "value of parameter a now is:  %d \n", a);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "bye bye qworld\n");

}

module_init(f1);
module_exit(f2);


MODULE_AUTHOR("l");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("experimanting with parameters");
```

Now when I try to echo a value to it, I get the "Permission Desnied" error, as expected:

```
[root@localhost param]# insmod p.ko 
[root@localhost param]# dmesg -c
[ 7247.734491] hello world
[ 7247.734498]   value passed: 5 
[root@localhost param]# echo 32 >/sys/module/
Display all 145 possibilities? (y or n)
[root@localhost param]# echo 32 >/sys/module/p/parameters/a 
bash: /sys/module/p/parameters/a: Permission denied
```

So far so good.

However, I can write to the file a using vim.

It does try to warn me with the follwing messages at the status line:

```
"/sys/module/p/parameters/a"
"/sys/module/p/parameters/a" E667: Fsync failed
WARNING: Original file may be lost or damaged
don't quit the editor until the file is successfully written!
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But I force the write with ! and get out of vim, and to my surprise the value of the parameter is re-written!

```
[root@localhost param]# vim /sys/module/p/parameters/a 
[root@localhost param]# cat /sys/module/p/parameters/a 
32
```

(Oriuginal value was 5 and I wrote 32 using vim).

Not only that, the value of the parameter in the module is changed as well!!:

```
[root@localhost param]# rmmod p.ko
[root@localhost param]# dmesg -c
[ 7616.109704] value of parameter a now is:  32 
[ 7616.109709] bye bye qworld
[root@localhost param]#
```

What does this mean? READ Only permissions can just be overruled by a userland application like vim? What is the use of permission bits then..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/sys` (sysfs) filesystem is somewhat special; many operations are not possible, for example creating or removing a file. Changing the permissions and ownership of a file or setting an ACL is permitted; that allows the system administrator to allow certain users or groups to access certain kernel entry points.

There is no special case that restricts a file that's initially read-only for everyone from being changed to being writable for some. That's what Vim does when it is thwarted in its initial attempt to save.

The permissions are the only thing that prevent the file from being written. Thus, if they're changed, the file content changes, which for a module parameter changes the parameter value inside the module.

Normally this doesn't have any security implication since only root can change the permissions on the file and root can change the value through `/dev/kmem` or by loading another module. It's something to keep in mind if root is restricted from loading modules or accessing physical memory directly by a security framework such as SELinux; the security framework needs to be configured to forbid problematic permission changes under `/sys`. If a user is given ownership of the file, they'll be able to change the permissions; to avoid this, if a specific user needs to have permission to read a parameter, don't `chown` the file to that user, but set an ACL (`setfacl -m u:alice:r /sys/…`).

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! I have another small follow-up question if/whenever you have time.. When I check the permission bit of the file system entry corresponding to the parameter, it's still `-r--r--r--`. Does this mean that Vim first changes the permission bits to allow write, then changes it back to what it was before?

Comment: @Lavya Yes (run `strace -o vim.strace vim /sys/module/p/parameters/a` to see what it does).